# A group of order $36$ with a normal subgroup of order $9$.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

I have to solve the following exercise of group theory:

Let $G$ be a non-abelian group of order $36$ for which there exists $\varphi:G \rightarrow H$ a group morphism such that $|Im\varphi|=4$. The exercise ask to find all possible value of $n_2$, the number of the $2$-Sylow subgroups.

Since $|Im\varphi|=4$, in $G$ we have a normal subgroup of order $9$, the kernel $K$. For the  Sylow's theorem the number of $2$-Sylow's subgroups $n_2$ must divide $9$ and it is equal to $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. So we have as a possibility for $n_2$ the following values: $1,3,9$. If $n_2=1$, there is a unique $N$ subgroup of order $4$ so it is normal. Since $K$ is normal and $K \cap N=\{e\}$, $KN$ is a subgroup of $G$ and must coincide with $G$. Moreover $K$ and $N$ ar abelian subgroup since their order is the square of a prime number, and since $K \cap N=\{e\}$, each element of $N$ commutes with each element of $K$. From this reasoning I can conclude that $G$ is an abelian group and this goes against the hypothesis. Thus $n_2 \neq 1$, is there an error in my reasoning?

Comment: The dihedral group of order $36$ has a normal subgroup of order $9$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $12$ groups of order $36$ having a normal subgroup of order $9$, namely the $4$ abelian groups, and $8$ non-abelian ones, e.g., a nontrivial extension of the dihedral group $D_9$ by $C_2$, $C_9\ltimes (C_2\times C_2)$, $(C_3\times C_3)\ltimes C_4$, $(C_3\times C_3)\ltimes (C_2\times C_2)$, and $D_{18}$.

Reference: [Notes by Wodzicki](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ewodzicki/257/G36.pdf).

Comment: Where is the wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: Yes, maybe the wrong is that I don't know if such $N$ is also normal.

Comment: Moreover, if $n_2=1$ I have an absurd, since the unique $N$ is normal, and my reasoning in this case is correct?

Comment: I haven't understood yet your argument with commuting. You should take one explicit example, like $D_{18}$ and write down every step again.

Comment: One of order $9$ and one of order $4$ must be disjoint, no?

Comment: If $N \cap K = \{e\}$ and are both normal, for every $n \in N, k \in K$, the element $n^{-1}knk^{-1} \in N \cap K$, thus $nk=kn$.

Comment: They are not both normal. Take $D_{18}$.

Comment: Yes, this allow me to conclude that mustn't exists an unique subgroup of order $4$, no? The only possible values for $n_2$ is $3, 9$.

Comment: Right. There exists in general only either a unique Sylow $2$-subgroup or a unique Sylow $3$-subgroup for a group of order $36$.

Answer (score 0):

You have proved that $G$ is the **semidirect** product of $K$ by $N$. This is where $K$ is normal, $N$ is a subgroup, and $K\cap N=1$. Semidirect products need not be abelian, for example $S_3$ is one. You are thinking that is enough for $G$ to be a **direct** product, which is where $N$ is also normal.

Comment: I know that if $N$ and $K$ are two normal subgroups of $G$ such that $N \cap K=1$, then each element of $K$ commutes with each element of $N$.

Comment: But you have only shown that $N$ is a subgroup, not normal.